# How do I create a superuser if I have deployed Django app via git?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, heroku

So I have an SQLite database in development in the settings.py of the root Django project.

settings.py is as follows (regarding databases):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

However, as you can see, my app is up and running on heroku, and the data there is on a **PostgreSQL** database.

My method of deployment to production for this application has been **git**, and I kind of like the idea of just pushing to github repository and then clicking deploy on heroku.

However, I'm quite confused on how to manage this difference in databases. If I were to use **heroku-cli**, there seem to be a lot of commands to do things with the database, but since I'm just using **git** I really have no idea how to go about it.
Here's a list of equivalent commands I'd like to know how to perform through git:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

```
$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

I have tried doing these on development, migrating there and then pushing to github, but obviously that only changes the SQLite database and does nothing to the production postgresql database. Any idea on how should I do that?

Comment: you can ssh into your heroku env and run the createsuperuser command there - you can also write a simple script that creates a superuser on deploy if one does not exist and remove it one subsequent deploys - i do agree there should be an easier way to do this

Comment: >you can also write a simple script that creates a superuser on deploy if one does not exist and remove it one subsequent deploys - -----Can you show me how to do that? Also, thank you for the answer

Comment: This isn't a *Git* thing: Git just manages commits. Your database is outside Git (and for good reason; it should stay that way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom Django manage.py command
(https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://medium.com/swlh/creating-custom-manage-py-commands-with-django-733ec7509b2&ved=2ahUKEwiQ9eeHvfnvAhVeAp0JHRx0CWEQFjACegQIAxAF&usg=AOvVaw2_Lk0kE2U0khALAxjb0hQ9)

to create a superuser if one does not exist.Then, in your Procfile, you can set a release command like:

`release: python manage.py <su_command>`

Comment: This is probably a better practice than my answer.

Comment: Thank you:), Both to you and Daniel. Although this is a really good answer, I already changed the deployment from github to herokucli and now I can do things more elegantly through cmd.

Answer (score 2):

Place this in one of your .py files:

```py
if not User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).first():
    user = User.objects.create(
        username = 'admin',
        email = 'admin@mywebsite.com',
        is_superuser = True,
        ...
    )
    user.set_password('some password')
    user.save()
```

Then remove it after the first deploy - and don't forget to change your password!